# Unresolved constraint in bundle suddenly in new version of JBossFuse

Tags: osgi, bundle, jbossfuse

I have already searched for solution online but none of them has actually worked. I am moving from JBossFuse 6.2.1. to JbossFuse 6.3.0. This includes upgrading dependencies which I have managed, most of them. Right now I am stuck with this error:

> Error executing command: Error starting bundles:
>   Unable to start bundle 390: Unresolved constraint in bundle pipeline-reception-ws-external-cxf [390]: Unable to resolve 390.0: missing requirement [390.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl)

I am using maven-bundle-plugin which is configured this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Import-Package>
                org.apache.camel.*;version="[${camel.range.start},${camel.range.end})",
                ms.common.wsdl,template.velocity,org.eclipse.jetty.server,*
            </Import-Package>
            <Export-Package>
                eu.unicorn.basse.ms.pipeline.reception.route.ws.external.cxf.*
            </Export-Package>
            <_removeheaders>Import-Service</_removeheaders>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am not sure why this does not work if it works on older JbossFuse environment. Question is, how to solve this issue.

Comment: try `exports|grep org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl` command - maybe there is such bundle that exports `org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl` package and you simply doesn't declare `org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl` in `Import-Package`.

Comment: maven-bundle-plugin can discover lots of packages to import, but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that your environment does not contain a bundle which exports the package `org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl`. As there is no version information in your package import it indicates that you also don't have a suitably bundled version of it in your bundle's build path (if you did then the maven-bundle-plugin would have found a version and added it to your import).

Either this requirement on `org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl` is new to your bundle, or it was previously supplied by another bundle in Fuse 6.2.1 which is no longer present in Fuse 6.3.0.

In any event you need to start by fixing your bundle, either by putting the relevant parts of Jetty on the build path so that you get a version range on your import, or by removing the new dependency which has leaked into your bundle. Then, if needed, you can simply deploy the other bundles that your bundle requires.